# How to show this lemma ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How to show this lemma ? Let $ P $ be a $ p $-group and let $ N $ be a nontrivial, elementary abelian normal subgroup of $ P $ which has a complement $ X $ in $ P $. If $ P=\langle y \rangle X $ for some element $ y $, then $ \vert N \vert = p $ if $ p > 2 $ and $ \vert N \vert \leq 4 $ if $ p = 2 $.